# How to dynamically link cppunit on Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, linker, g++

I have installed GNU g++ and cppunit using this command:

```
brew install gcc cppunit
```

The library seems to be correctly installed:

```
$ find / -name "libcppunit*" 2> /dev/null
/usr/local/lib/libcppunit-1.14.0.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libcppunit.a
/usr/local/lib/libcppunit.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/cppunit/1.14.0/lib/libcppunit-1.14.0.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/cppunit/1.14.0/lib/libcppunit.a
/usr/local/Cellar/cppunit/1.14.0/lib/libcppunit.dylib
```

Here is a code I wrote that makes use of cppunit. The file is named `test.cpp`. Ignore the fact that there is no test runner in this code. I am only concerned about linking at this time.

```
#include <cppunit/extensions/HelperMacros.h>
#include <iostream>

class FooTest : public CppUnit::TestFixture
{
protected:
    void testBasic()
    {
        CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(1 + 1, 2);
    }

    void testBasic2()
    {
        CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(1 + 2, 3);
    }
private:
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE(FooTest);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(testBasic);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(testBasic2);
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END();
};

CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_REGISTRATION(FooTest);

int main()
{
    std::cout << "hello\n";
    return 0;
}
```

How can I dynamically link it with cppunit now? The following attempt failed:

```
$ g++ -lcppunit test.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "CppUnit::SourceLine::SourceLine(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
      FooTest::testBasic()     in ccyx1sc9.o
      FooTest::testBasic2()      in ccyx1sc9.o
  "CppUnit::AdditionalMessage::AdditionalMessage(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      void CppUnit::assertEquals<int>(int const&, int const&, CppUnit::SourceLine, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) in ccyx1sc9.o
  "CppUnit::TestFactoryRegistry::getRegistry(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      CppUnit::AutoRegisterSuite<FooTest>::AutoRegisterSuite() in ccyx1sc9.o
...
...
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the "g++" from Homebrew?  Is "/usr/local/lib" in your library search path?

Comment: @MilesBudnek Yes, `g++ --version` shows `g++ (Homebrew GCC 8.1.0) 8.1.0`. `which g++` shows `/usr/local/bin/g++`. `g++ -L/usr/local/lib -lcppunit test.cpp` also leads to the same error, so I don't think this is due to library search path being incorrect.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Also, if `g++` were unable to find the library, we would get an error like this: `g++ -lfoo test.cc` - `ld: library not found for -lfoo`. Since we did not get such an error, it seems the problem is not the library search path.